# Django serializer returns empty list

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, orm

I have a class-based view that returns all the data in the table. But while accessing the URL all I get is an empty list.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class EmployeeModel(models.Model):
    EmpID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    EmpName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Salary = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'employeetable'
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import EmployeeModel
from .serializers import EmployeeSerialize

class EmployeeTable(APIView):

    def get(self,request):
        emp_obj = EmployeeModel.objects.all()
        empserializer = EmployeeSerialize(emp_obj,many=True)
        return Response(empserializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import EmployeeModel

class EmployeeSerialize(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import EmployeeTable, transformer_list

urlpatterns = [
    path('display/',EmployeeTable.as_view()),
]
```

The table has 5 rows. It is not empty.
I want to serialize all 5 rows

Comment: can you also provide a urls.py?

Comment: @Vagner Added urls.py

Comment: Verify that the EmployeeSerialize serializer is working as expected by running the serialization code in the Django shell. You can do this by running the following code: `from .serializers import EmployeeSerialize
from .models import EmployeeModel

emp_obj = EmployeeModel.objects.all()
empserializer = EmployeeSerialize(emp_obj,many=True)
print(empserializer.data)
`

Comment: `KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"` got his error while `from .serializers import EmployeeSerialize`

Comment: Should have added the app name to `from {appname}.models import EmployeeModel`. It is fixed, Thanks for the help mate.

Comment: good job. np :)

Answer (score 0):

I have also created the same but in my case, it worked see the below images

[image]

See my serializer

[image]

See my models below

[image]

and my output is here below

[image]

I think there are some issue at your code or some mistake can be there can you please provide full information

Comment: Should have added app name to `from {appname}.models import EmployeeModel`. IT is fixed, thanks